# WPF ListBox in TabItem "Property content set more than once"

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm (evidently) new to WPF and am struggling to figure out how to put a `ListBox` inside a `TabItem`. My current attempt below results in `Property 'Content' set more than once`, all the answers to which I can't seem to relate to mine.

```
<Window>
<Grid>
    <TabItem>
        <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <DockPanel Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Inventory" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
        <ListBox>
            <ListBoxItem>Test</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
   </TabItem>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that'd be appreciated.

Comment: What is the use of `<Grid Background="Red"></Grid>`? Remove it and see. That should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Edited answer which actually works is below. Indeed, as others suggest, removing the `"<Grid Background="Red"></Grid>"` line solves the problem. So does removing the following lines:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>Test</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

The Grid and ListBox views are both being set as the Content Property of the TabItem and this is the cause of the error.

If we truly wish to use both the ListBox to be the content of our TabItem, we need to place them both inside a stack panel, like below:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <DockPanel Width="130" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="Inventory" Foreground="Black" FontSize="30" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </DockPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Grid Background="Red"></Grid>

                <ListBox>
                    <ListBoxItem>Test</ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: IMO `<Grid Background="Red"></Grid>` is useless and thus it could be removed completely. +1 though..

Comment: Yes, this could be the case, but still the error needs to be properly understood by the OP :)

Comment: <TabItem.Header> Can't be placed in <StackPanel>. It needs to be a first-level descendant of TabItem.  Removing <Grid Background="Red"> would resolve the issue.

Comment: edited my answer, thanks for your comments. this should be ok now